# Не получается изменить массив char

Tags: c++, строки

Код:

```cpp
char** n = new char*[2];
n[1] = "ll";  // без этого след строка работает
n[1] = "k";
n[0] = "klk";
// n[0][1]='s'; тоже ошибка

cout << n << " " << n[0] << " " << n[0][1] << endl;
```

Ошибка:

> does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'

Почему вылетает такая ошибка? По факту я просто хочу переименовать элемент массива.

Comment: Вообще-то строковый литерал менять нельзя, т.е. это `const char*`, но никак не `char*`, как это пытаетесь сделать вы...

Comment: строка `"klk"` константная. `char const * * n= new char const * [ 2 ] ;`

Answer (score 3):

У Вас n это указатель на указатель, следовательно, Вам надо выделить память для каждого n[i]. То есть
`n[0] = new char[size];`
`n[1] = new char[size];`
а потом можете заполнить n[i] строками

Answer (score 2):

Если вы планируете просто хранить массив строковых литералов, то можно просто добавить `const`:

```
const char** n = new const char*[2];
n[1] = "ll";  // без этого след строка работает
n[1] = "k";
n[0] = "klk";

cout << n << " " << n[0] << " " << n[0][1] << endl;
```

Но вот *изменять* строковые литералы нельзя, так что

```
n[0][1]='s';
```

так ошибкой и останется. Если вы хотите хранить *копии* литералов с правом их изменения — надо выделять место для них и копировать.

Но я бы в этом случае рекомендовал работать со строками `string`, и не массивами, а векторами.

Ведь у вас же С++, как-никак...

Answer (score -1):

Строковые литералы в C++ всегда являются константами, поэтому надо привести `const char*` ко `char*`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char** a = new char*[3];
    a[0] = (char*) "abc";
    a[1] = (char*) "def";
    a[2] = (char*) "ghi";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << "\n";
    }
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

```
a[0] = abc
a[1] = def
a[2] = ghi
```

Comment: От этого константность строкового литерала ("abc", "def" и т.д.) никуда не исчезнет. Суть в том, что компилятор размещает строковые литералы в памяти, которая запрещена для изменения (на уровне управления памятью в ОС  эти страницы имеют атрибут write-protect)

Comment: Очень плохое решение...